# How to create/access scopend beans in Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, scope, javabeans

I know that I can put beans into request and session. How to create application scoped bean? Should I use servlet context for this?

Comment: @MockerTim: OP doesn't seem to be using JSF, but plain old JSP/Servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In servlet you can use

> getServletContext().setAttribute("name", "value")

and in jsp

> jsp:useBean class="foo.Counter" scope="application"